# Recorrido de nodos y unificación de impuestos

Tags: php

Tengo el siguiente problema estoy intentado mostrar impuestos de una factura en una tabla de la siguiente manera.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema está en que mi arreglo guarda los resultados de cada nodo aunque este no cumpla con la validación, y esto ocasiona que me arroje demasiados resultados y no respete las columnas y haga esto:

Para dar una mejor perspectiva les mostrare como está la información dentro del archivo. [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora en mi CONTROLADOR tengo la siguiente función que recorre los nodos y guarda los importes e impuestos en arreglos:

```
    foreach ($xml->xpath('//cfdi:Comprobante//cfdi:Impuestos//cfdi:Traslados//cfdi:Traslado') as $nodo){
    $var = $nodo['importe'];
    $vari = $nodo['impuesto'];

    if($aux != $vari && ($aux != 'IEPS')){
        if($vari != 'ISR'){
            $arr_d[]=$var;
            $arr_c[]=$vari;
        }
    }       $aux=$vari;

}
```

En mi vista imprimo los arreglos con un ciclo for y los imprimo en una tabla de la siguiente manera:

```
if($impuestos_r == 'IEPS'){
        echo "<td>";
        echo $importes_r;
        echo "</td>";
        }else{

        $importes_r=0;
        echo "<td>";
        echo $importes_r;
        echo "</td>";}
```

¿Qué puedo hacer para que solo muestre un resultado dependiendo del tipo de impuesto del que se trata?

Deseo que en la tabla en el campo IEPS imprima el importe correspondiente y en caso de que no exista el nodo con impuesto IEPS imprima un cero.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Por favor, no pongas imagenes de tu codigo, si no que copia tu codigo en la pregunta.

Comment: porque no agrupas tus impuestos, puedes tener `$impuestos[$impuesto] = $total_impuesto;`

Comment: El problema es que estas haciendo el for basado en la cantidad de impuestos, cuando primero debes de recorrer tus impuestos/traslados, y de cada traslado debes recorrer sus impuestos, despues recorres impuestos/retenciones y lo mismo, haces un agrupamiento de impuestos, `$impuestos['traslado']['IVA'] += $total_impuesto;  $impuestos['retenciones']['IVA'] += $total_impuesto;`, y asi tendrias las cantidades que estas necesitando.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes realizar lo siguiente

```
$impuestos_trasladados = array();
foreach ($xml->xpath('//cfdi:Comprobante//cfdi:Impuestos//cfdi:Traslados//cfdi:Traslado') as $nodo){

    if(!isset($impuestos_trasladados[$nodo['impuesto']])) {
        $impuestos_trasladados[(string) $nodo['impuesto']] = $nodo['importe'];
    } else {
        $impuestos_trasladados[(string) $nodo['impuesto']] += $nodo['importe'];
    }
} 
$impuestos_cfdis[] = $impuestos_trasladados;
```

al realizar tu impresión, obtienes los impuestos de ese cfdi

```
$impuestos_imprimir = $impuestos_cfdis[$i];

echo "<td>" . (isset($impuestos_imprimir['IVA'])?$impuestos_imprimir['IVA']:"-")."</td>";
echo "<td>" . (isset($impuestos_imprimir['IEPS'])?$impuestos_imprimir['IEPS']:"-")."</td>";
```

Comment: Lo implementé y me aparece este error en el if      Illegal offset type in isset or empty

Comment: `$nodo['impuesto']`te devuelve las cadenas 'IVA', 'IEPS', 'ISR' o alguna otra, de no ser así, debería ser la cadena del impuesto como llave dell arreglo, podrías colocar la salida de un `print_r($nodo["impuesto"]);`.

Comment: Puedes verificar con el cambio de convertir a `string` los atributos `$impuestos_trasladados[(string) $nodo['impuesto']]`